# Interactive webcam

Tags: flash, user-interface

I want to move objects in Flash with my hands via the webcam. How can I do this?

Comment: Please rephrase or try to explain in more detail.

Comment: what have you done so far (the SO mantra)

Answer (score 2):

Easy. Read the image stream from the webcam, locate your hands in the image, parse motion of hands as a command to manipulate whatever objects you want to manipulate. Voilà!

Comment: Easy? Shape recognition for something like hands is extremely hard to do. A black rectangle is something, but hands can rotate, change shape and a lot more. I'd advise to seriously rethink this..

Comment: @evilpenguin2 - A bit of a whoosh!  But that is what the OP is asking  to be done.

Comment: do u have any example for these ??? fla file??? plz